# Order by meta value

Tags: meta-query

I've a custom post type that has a custom filed called **deck-number** and client wants to sort the result by deck number. FYI, deck numbers are numeric values. So I used query like bellow.

```
get_posts('post_type=decks&nopaging=true&meta_key=deck-number&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC');
```

The issue I'm facing is I'm getting result sorting like 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

I need your advice to solve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `meta_value_num` with `orderby` instead of `meta_value`.

`meta_value` is used to order alphabetically.
`meta_value_num` used to order numerically.

For more information, check this: [Codex get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters)
And this for detailed information: [Codex WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: You saved my day :)